# Geo Coordinates (Long,Lat) to Meters (x,y)

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates

I am working coordinates system as shown below:

[image]

x and y are in meters. I am interested in only positive x,y. I want to convert (x,y) to (lat,lon) and vise versa.

I thought it is simple and I dont see a problem with my solutions below. But I am not getting very correct results.

**My Solution:**

As we see in the image below, I considered the Latitude and Longitude as angles of 2 circles:

[image]

**1. (x,y) to (lat,lon)**

I applied the Arc Length formula ([here](https://formulas.tutorvista.com/math/angle-formulas.html)), shown below, on both; x and y
[image]
[image]

Hence, my functions are:

```
private static double calculateLat(float x) {
    int earthRadius = 6371000;
    return REF_LOC.getLatitude() + x*360/(2*PI*earthRadius);
}

private static double calculateLong(float y) {
    int earthRadius = 6371000;
    return REF_LOC.getLongitude() + y*360/(2*PI*earthRadius);
}
```

REF_LOC is the reference Geo Location for which (x,y) are (0,0). It can be any point on earth.

**2. (lat,lon) to (x,y)**

For this I am simply using this:

```
int calculateX(double longitude){
        Location.distanceBetween(REF_LOC.getLatitude(), REF_LOC.getLongitude(),
                REF_LOC.getLatitude(), lonDeg, results);
        return results[0];
}

int calculateY(double latitude){
        Location.distanceBetween(REF_LOC.getLatitude(), REF_LOC.getLongitude(),
                latDeg, REF_LOC.getLongitude(), results);
        return results[0];
}
```

But I am getting inconsistent results. First I use solution 1 and convert some value (x,y) to (lat,long). But when I use the same (lat,long) back to (x,y) using solution 2, I get about 2 meters difference in x and 10 meters in y. Can anyone help me identify the problem please?

Comment: I estimate that the difference results in the fact your (1) is modeling a sphere whereas the (2) (which uses Location.distanceBetween) is modeling an ellipsoid, where the axis of the ellipsoid are defined as:        `double a = 6378137.0; // WGS84 major axis` _and_ 
        `double b = 6356752.3142; // WGS84 semi-major axis`

Comment: Also check out https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25494/how-accurate-is-approximating-the-earth-as-a-sphere for explanation of error magnitude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alluding to my comment on spherical vs elliptical calculations, another way to look at difference in distance calculations for spherical vs elliptical distance is to use the 2 available utilities:

```
// For REF_LOC = (70, 20)

// Compute a lat/lng due east of a REF_LOC and compute distance using both
// available methods.

LatLng P = SphericalUtil.computeOffsetOrigin(REF_LOC, 20000, 90.0);

// And then compute a distance 
d = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(REF_LOC, P);
Location.distanceBetween(REF_LOC.latitude, REF_LOC.longitude, P.latitude, P.longitude, results);

// d = 20000.000000000036
// results[0] = 20081.818


// and for a REF_LOC = (0, 20)
// d = 20000.000000000127
// results[0] = 20022.377
```

What's also interesting is the SphericalUtil.computeOffsetOrigin() produces error
in latitude increasing from equator to pole making it non-symmetrical.  Yet the resulting distances are essentially exact.

I'd recommend using SphericalUtil.computeOffsetOrigin to compute the X/Y breaking
it into the latitude and longitude offsets as you are doing.

Finally demonstrating the SphericalUtil solution:

```
// Start with some arbitrary x/y relative to REF_LOC
double Rx = 125.0;
double Ry = 73.0;

// Compute a lat/lon from REF_LOC to the point
LatLng Rll = new LatLng(SphericalUtil.computeOffsetOrigin(REF_LOC, Ry, 180).latitude,
            SphericalUtil.computeOffsetOrigin(REF_LOC, Rx, 270).longitude);

// And recompute the x/y components of the lat/lon

double Rxx = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(REF_LOC, new LatLng(REF_LOC.latitude, Rll.longitude));
double Ryy = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(REF_LOC, new LatLng(Rll.latitude, REF_LOC.longitude));
```

Resulting in:

```
Rx/Ry   = (125.0, 73.0)
Rxx/Ryy = (125.00000004545973, 73.00000000137051)
```

Acceptable error I assume.

So the parting question is - what does the x/y really represent?

Reference the source for both utilities for more information:

[Location](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/location/java/android/location/Location.java)

[SphericalUtil](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java)

Comment: This has worked! Though if i use Location.distanceBetween() in ur solution instead of SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(), it gives incorrect result. Probably cz they use different radius values. Well, the conversion is consistent (back n forth) but I have yet to test it on ground and see if it gives correct results. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just found out that I had to reverse the Angles (0 -> 180 and 90 ->270) to make it work. Otherwise the location was on the negative side.

Comment: Yes, the computeOffsetOrigin is 'TO' so in the Spherical solution it should be what you indicated for heading to put the point in quadrant one.  Code updated - thanks.